# Set Express Checkout: ReturnURL and CancelURL are Invalid

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am using Paypal Recurring Payment with Express Checkout. Now i am facing error in ReturnURL and CancelURL please check the bellow files.

Array
(

```
[TIMESTAMP] => 2017 d10 d04T06 a31 a53Z
[CORRELATIONID] => a7c6c48585ebb
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 123 e0
[BUILD] => 39073839
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10471
[L_ERRORCODE1] => 10472
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument e See additional error messages for details e
[L_SHORTMESSAGE1] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument e See additional error messages for details e
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => ReturnURL is invalid e
[L_LONGMESSAGE1] => CancelURL is invalid e
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
[L_SEVERITYCODE1] => Error
```

)

Here is my SetExpressCheckout Method:

```
$SECFields = array(
                        'token' => '',                              
                        'maxamt' => '6.98',                      
                        'returnurl' => 'https://musiculus.com/frontend/payment_plus',           
                        'cancelurl' => 'https://musiculus.com/frontend/membership',                 
                        'callback' => '',                           
                        'callbacktimeout' => '',                    
                        'callbackversion' => '61.0',                
                        'reqconfirmshipping' => '0',                
                        'noshipping' => '1',                        
                        'allownote' => '0',                         
                        'addroverride' => '1',                      
                        'localecode' => '',                         
                        'pagestyle' => '',                          
                        'hdrimg' => '',                             
                        'hdrbordercolor' => '',                      
                        'hdrbackcolor' => '',                       
                        'payflowcolor' => '',                       
                        'skipdetails' => '',                        
                        'email' => '',                              
                        'solutiontype' => '',                       
                        'landingpage' => '',                        
                        'channeltype' => '',                        
                        'giropaysuccessurl' => '',                  
                        'giropaycancelurl' => '',                   
                        'banktxnpendingurl' => '',              
                        'brandname' => '',                            
                        'customerservicenumber' => '',              
                        'giftmessageenable' => '',                  
                        'giftreceiptenable' => '',                  
                        'giftwrapenable' => '',                     
                        'giftwrapname' => '',                       
                        'giftwrapamount' => '',                     
                        'buyeremailoptionenable' => '',             
                        'surveyquestion' => 'Are you listing?',     
                        'surveyenable' => '',                       
                        'totaltype' => '',                          
                        'notetobuyer' => '',                                            
                        'buyerid' => '',                            
                        'buyerusername' => '',                      
                        'buyerregistrationdate' => '',              
                        'allowpushfunding' => ''                    
                    );
```

Here is the return url from paypal:
[image]

Thanks for any help.